# The assert statement does not work in c++

Tags: c++

I have experienced a strange problem when using assert in my program.
The program does not terminate even when I add a line of code`assert(false)`.
But the `assert` works when I write several lines of sample code. Anybody know why it happened?

Comment: Could be helpful to see some code

Comment: assert works in C++. To tell you why your code doesn't work, we'd need to see that.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Debug configuration so that `assert` is not simply stripped off by the prepocessor?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have:

```
#define NDEBUG
```

this turns all `assert`'s into `nop`'s.

Answer (score 2):

If you have differing behaviour, depending on the amount of code, then I guess you don't have `NDEBUG` defined and I would guess the compiler is simply compiling out the redundant code.

More details about environment are required, however, you give a definitive answer.